# construct a isomorphism between $M^{l}(\phi)$ and $L(F/Im\phi;E)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\phi: E \to F$ be a linear mapping. The space $M^{l}(\phi)$ of linear mappings  $\psi: F \to E$ such that $\psi \circ \phi=0$

$L(F/\operatorname{Im}\phi;E)$ where $E,F$ are vector space, is the  set of linear mappings  $\tau: F/Im\phi \to E$

construct a isomorphism between $M^{l}(\phi)$ and $L(F/\operatorname{Im} \phi;E)$.
Assume that a property of $M^{l}(\phi)$ is that is the set of linear mappings such that $Im(\phi)\subset \operatorname{Ker}\psi$

I was reading webner Greub's linear algebra book and I came across this exercise (exercise 5, chapter 2), this is my diet:

Let $\psi \in M^{l}(\phi)$, since  $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)\subset \operatorname{Ker}\psi$ then $\psi$
induces a linear mapping

$$\overline{\psi}: F/\operatorname{Im}\phi \to E$$

such that $\overline{\psi}\circ \pi=\psi$, where $\pi: F \to F/\operatorname{Im}\phi$

then: $$M^{l}(\phi) \to L(F/\operatorname{Im}\phi; E)$$ define by $\psi \to \overline{\psi}$ is an isomorphism (
I need to prove that this function that I define is an isomorphism)